# how to call mdi form by function

Tags: c#, mdi

How do I create a function for following code so that i may not have to write the following whole code to make a form be used as MDICHILD Form.

```
Students stu = null;
    private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (stu == null || stu.IsDisposed)
        {
            stu = new Students();
            stu.MdiParent = this;
            stu.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            stu.Activate();
        }
    }
```

while I want it like this

```
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreateMdiChild(Students);
    }
```

and function should be like this

```
public void CreateMdiChild(Form form)
    {
        //expected code            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the method generic, e.g. :

```
public void CreateMdiChildOrActivate<T>(ref T instance) where T : Form, new()
{
    if (instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
    {
        instance = new T();
        instance.MdiParent = this;
        instance.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        instance.Activate();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateMdiChildOrActivate(ref this.stu);
}
```

**EDIT :**

If you don't want to create a class field for each form, you can do in this way:

Create a class dictionary field containing the open form for each form-type:

```
private Dictionary<Type,Form> openForms = new Dictionary<Type,Form>();
```

Then change the previous method to:

```
public void CreateMdiChildOrActivate<T>() where T : Form, new()
{
    Form instance;
    openForms.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out instance);
    if (instance == null || instance.IsDisposed)
    {
        instance = new T();
        openForms[typeof(T)] = instance;
        instance.MdiParent = this;
        instance.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        instance.Activate();
    }
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
private void studentsToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateMdiChildOrActivate<Student>();
}
```

Comment: @kashif: sorry I didn't understand... you want to call this method without passing any parameters ?

Comment: @kashif: if I understand you correctly you don't want to create a class field called Stu, but let the thing to the method, by passing just the type of the form to it, right ? Check my edit, I hope is what you want...

Comment: @kashif: They're both good, but the 2nd one is probably better if you have more than 3-4 forms to open because you don't need to have a lot of fields in the form. On the other hand, the second case allows only one instance of form for each form-type (e.g. just one Student form possible, not more...) but I think that's what you want...

Comment: what about my new Answer??

Comment: I asked you this question in March. at that time I was not aware of Generics. Now I have a little knowledge. I think iterating through the mdi parant to look for the instance you are passing for <T> and then if the instance is found just activating it else instantiating <T> and then telling <T> what is its MdiParant and then showing it is better then storing all the forms in Dictionary. digEmAll can you plz tell what does where do in generics??

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand your comment... however I suggest you to open another question, in this way you can explain what's your problem, what do you want to achieve posting code samples etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
public void CreateMdiChild<T>(Form f) where T : Form, new()
{
    foreach (Form frm in f.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frm.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {                        
            if (frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                frm.Activate();
            }
            return;
        }                    
    }
    T t = new T();
    t.MdiParent = f;
    t.Show();
}
```

**Usage**

```
CreateMdiChild<MyForm>()
```