# how to call MdiChild from MDIParent form

Tags: c#, mdichild, mdiparent

I create a new MdiChild from MainForm using this method:

```
AdminLogInForm adminForm;
 private void LogInAsAdminMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (adminForm == null)
        {
            adminForm = new AdminLogInForm();
            adminForm.MdiParent = this;
            adminForm.Show();
            adminForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            adminForm.BringToFront();
            LogInAsAdminMenuItem.Enabled = false;              
        }
        else
        {
            adminForm.Activate();
            adminForm.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Why when i close my child, using in chld form "this.close()" using that method i cant open it anymore?

there i call close();

```
        private void cancelLogInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MdiParent.Activate();            
        if(this.MdiParent!=null)
        ((MainForm)this.MdiParent).LogInAsAdminMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        this.Close();
    }
```

by the way to make work that I asked before I hed to plase  this.Close(); after all statements .

Comment: By the time I answered your question, you changed the question. Now please show where do you call Close() function and where you intend to open it.

Comment: thnx, I edited, plased function calling close() it is on child form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By closing the form you are not making `adminForm` instance to null (Which is what your if condition will check when you try to open it next time.)

On diposal of your form make `adminForm` = `null` and then your if condition will work next time.

```
private void LogInAsAdminMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (adminForm == null)
        {
            adminForm = new AdminLogInForm(this);
            adminForm.Disposed += new EventHandler(adminForm_Disposed); //Add Disposed EventHandler
            adminForm.MdiParent = this;
            adminForm.Show();
            adminForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            adminForm.BringToFront();
            LogInAsAdminMenuItem.Enabled = false;              
        }
        else
        {
            adminForm.Activate();
            adminForm.BringToFront();
        }
    }

    void adminForm_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        adminForm = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Described by Marshal that the closing of a form makes it disposed you should add a condition for disposing as well like this

```
AdminLogInForm adminForm;

private void LogInAsAdminMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (adminForm == null || adminForm.IsDisposed)
        {
            adminForm = new AdminLogInForm();
            adminForm.MdiParent = this;
            adminForm.Show();
            adminForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            adminForm.BringToFront();
            LogInAsAdminMenuItem.Enabled = false;              
        }
        else
        {
            adminForm.Activate();
            adminForm.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

Or you can also create a function to use a form as mdi 
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870532)